# Searching list with while

Tags: python, list

Is there a better way to search this list? (the number of elements change over time) after input. The program is executed as long as we don't enter a valid item.

```
items = ['car','cat','house','fish']
item = input('Item:')
while item not in items:
    print('Item not found.')
    item = input('Item:')
print('Item founded!')
```

Comment: *number of elements change over time* -- Not in the code you've given...

Comment: You might want to consider changing `items` to a set, but you would only really notice a difference for lists that are hundreds of thousands of items.  This code seems fine.

Comment: Not here, but in my project where this is just a part of function.

Comment: Okey, @PatrickHaugh .